# Devise integration with Remote Authentication and local database authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to setup two authenticaton with my application(Remote and local Database authentication). but I don't seem how it works?

Comment: Remote authentication means?

Comment: Remote Authentication means I have an api of another server from where I need to authenticate the user and after authentication user can login in my application if I'll get access token from that server.